# When I press space instead of search I'm getting playback started

Tags: shortcut

Blender 2.8.
It can be Layout or Modleing tap opened, but when I press Space instead of search menu animation starts playing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 2.8x Search is <kbd>F3</kbd>. For this and other shortcuts see https://www.ablenderuser.in/2019/01/blender-key-map.html?m=1